# Full Access user removed from NTFS Share

Tags: ntfs, network-share

I don't know how it happened but for some reason one of the sub folders in the Network shares (call the share Market and the sub folder Support) no longer has any groups or users with full permissions on the share. The Market top level has users and groups with these permissions and everything is set up for folder inheritance but it's not inheriting permissions from the top level and only has modify permissions for the single group that is in the Access List for the sub folder Support. I can see items in the sub folder but I can not add, edit, or delete permissions to the Support folder. What are my options so I can once again manage permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take ownership of the folder then you can change the permissions to be what you need them to be.  Make sure to change the permissions and under advanced choose to replace child permissions

Answer (score 1):

Çheck ownership of the sub folder.  If you don't have it, take over ownership.  That should hopefully allow you to propagate permissions.  You also may have to re-apply your top level permissions so that they get pushed down again to the sub folder.